# ext.grid.editorgridpanel validation if two duplicate data of rows exists

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have this code below and I have seen on the internet somewhere, but it is working only with one header or row exists.

I would like to have that if two rows exists, it will validate. Let us say that I have header of name and date, if name and date data were duplicate, it will raise validation message duplicate of data cannot be save

```
var duplicated = function(store, number, value)
{
    var found = false;
    store.each(function(record)
        {
          if(found = (record.data[number]==value) ? true : false){return false};
        }
    )
    return found;
}
```

I've tried to manipulate that piece of code but I cannot do anymore.

---

I still can't figure it out. If the two data on rows already exists and if will save it will validate because it has two duplicate rows (two duplicate data as well like stated above).

Comment: Maybe, you should create a fiddle sample. https://fiddle.sencha.com

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check unique couples name+date add validators to your editors:

```
columns: [
{text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', getEditor: function(record) {
  return {
   xtype: 'textfield',
   validator: function (val) {
         const errMsg = 'Not unique';
         let isExist = false;
         store.each(function(rec){
            if(rec.get('name') === val && record.get(date) === rec.get('date')){
               isExist = true;
               return false;
              }
            });
            return val && !isExist ? true: errMsg ;
        }
    }
 }
},{text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', getEditor: function(record) {
  return {
   xtype: 'datefield',
   validator: function(val) {
        const errMsg = 'Not unique';
         let isExist = false;
         store.each(function(rec){
            if(rec.get('date') === val && record.get(name) === rec.get('name')){
               isExist = true;
               return false;
              }
            });
            return val && !isExist ? true: errMsg ;
}
}
 }
}
]
```

You can redo this more pretty, but hope that idea is clear.